# Unity Ads cause black screen on iOS after closed

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, ads

We are trying to integrate Unity Ads 2.0 (beta 5) into our game. The implementation went fine, ads are being displayed, but the problem came when ads finish. On some device (iPod touch gen 5), after ad is finished a black screen appears. We tried waiting for some time but there is no progress. It only can be closed by pressing the Home button. If we tap furiously onto the black screen sometimes it will display a blue "Privacy Policy" text. Tapping on it will lead to a website... The ads finished fine on iPad 2, the same ads ( the same content, we watched and compared ) is fine on iPad but it fails on iPod. I've searched for awhile and found out that there was some problem like this occurred in the past (because meta-content is mismatched), don't know if this is the case or not though.

Here are my test project. Unity Ads 2.0 beta 5, on Unity 5.3.5f1 and xCode 7, iPod touch gen 5, iOS 9.0.2

One small problem, why Unity Ads 2.0 required to include WatchConnectivity.framework?

Here is my test project http://www99.zippyshare.com/v/HU7wjYSt/file.html

This question is a duplicate of my thread on Unity (presumed dead) forum http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-ads-2-0-causing-black-screen-on-lower-end-ios-devices.417239/

Answer (score 0):

For future references, there are some issues with ARMv7 devices, and has been addressed in Unity Ads 2.0 RC1. Read here for more information http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-ads-2-0-causing-black-screen-on-lower-end-ios-devices.417239/#post-2740360